# Index and Lists - Index out of range

Tags: python, list

Shouldn't the following code print? `100 100`

```
price = 100  # assigns 'price' reference to 100
price = [price] # creates a 'price' list with 1 element: [100]

for i in range(1, 3):
    print(price[0]) # prints 100
    price[i] = price[i - 1]
    price.append(price[i])
    print(price[i])
```

Getting a `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` error at line `price[i] = price[i - 1]`, but the line right before prints `100` successfully.  Shouldnt price[i] simply be getting assigned price[0] value?

Comment: Issue is when trying to access python[i], then it throws index out of range. Left statement is not even `evaluated`

Comment: You're trying to append items to a list, see below. You can't just assign a value at nonexistent index positions and expect the list to automatically append or grow itself.

Comment: (Btw if you know a priori the list will have at least 3 elements, you could initialize it to `price = [None] * 3` and you get `[None, None, None]`. Now you can directly assign to them. But, explicitly doing append is better practice.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to append to a list, trying to do that with an index won't exactly work because that index isn't present in the list:

```py
somelist = []
somelist[0] = 1
IndexError
```

So just use `append`

```py
for i in range(1,3):
    price.append(price[i-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to append items to a list, or more precisely to initialize a list with repeated copies of something. Here are Pythonic ways to do that:

```
# Use a list comprehension
>>> price = [100 for _ in range(3)]
[100, 100, 100]

# Use itertools.repeat
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.repeat(100, 3))
[100, 100, 100]
```

These are both faster than (repeatedly) doing `append()`, which is O(N), so repeatedly doing `append()` is O(N^2) on a long list, which gets very slow.

(Btw if you know a priori the list will have at least N elements, and N is large, you could initialize it to `price = [None] * N` and you get `[None, None, None...]`. Now you can directly assign to them. But, explicitly doing append is better practice for beginners.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are assigning at an index too great for the length of the array.

> for i in range(1, 3):

This initializes i to 1. Since arrays are zero-indexed, and the length of your array is 1 on the first pass, you will hit an `assignment out of range error` at the line you mentioned (when `i=1`).

Here is a minimal example showing the issue:

```
my_array = ["foo"]
my_array[1] = "bar" # throws assignment out of range error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a value to a list directly why this list has note a previous size defined. You have to use append to add elements to the position you want.

Check:

```py
# Check the value on our initial position
print(price[0])
for i in range(1, 3):
    price.append(price[i-1])
    print(price[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

That will not print out:

`100`

`100`

You initialized a list with 1 element, the size of that list is 1. However your range starts at 1 for the `for` loop , what's really happening is:

```
price = 100  # assigns 'price' to 100
price = [price] # creates a 'price' list with 1 element: [100]

for i in range(1, 3): # The list is 0-indexed, meaning price[0] contains 100
    print(price[0]) # prints 100 as it should
    price[i] = price[i - 1] # i is 1, price[i] is not an assigned value, i.e: you never assigned price[1]
    price.append(price[i]) # This doesn't execute because an exception was thrown
    print(price[i]) # Neither does this
```

To get the result you're looking for, this would work:

```
price = [100] # creates a 'price' list with 1 element: [100]

for i in range(0, 2): # Start at index 0
    print(price[i]) # Print current index
    price.append(price[i]) # Append current value of price[i] to the price list
```

To ensure everything appended as you expected you can test it with len:

`print(len(price))`

`Output:3`

However, it is a preferred way of appending as @smci has shown in his/her answer.